# 'AttributeError: 'dataProcess' object has no attribute 'load_data'' What aspect of OOP am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am trying to execute a function that is a method of class I have imported and instantiated in another script - however, terminal returns the following error

Here is the flow of my code (please ignore indentation errors)...

I create the class DataProcess with a function to load data in the first file

```
class dataProcess(object):

def __init__(self, out_rows, out_cols, data_path = "./data/train/img", ... img_type = "png"):

def load_data(self):

    mydata = dataProcess(self.img_rows, self.img_cols)
    imgs_train, imgs_mask_skulls = mydata.load_train_data()
    imgs_test = mydata.load_test_data()
    return imgs_train, imgs_mask_skulls, imgs_test
```

And then in the other file I try to instantiate the class and call the load_data function.

```
from dataProcess import *
from dataPreperation import *
from myUnet import *

class runUnet():

def __init__(self, img_rows=img_rows, img_cols=img_cols):


    self.img_rows = img_rows # set values for these as default in definition arguments or as shape of input data
    self.img_cols = img_cols

def train_and_predict(self):

    print("loading data")
    mydata = dataProcess(self.img_rows, self.img_cols)
    imgs_train, imgs_mask_skulls, imgs_test = mydata.load_data()
    print("loading data done")
    myUnet = myUnet(self.img_rows, self.img_cols)
    model = myUnet.get_unet()
    print("got unet")

    model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet.hdf5', 
        monitor='loss',
        verbose=1, 
        save_best_only=True)
    print('Fitting model...')

    model.fit(imgs_train, imgs_mask_skulls, 
        batch_size=4, 
        nb_epoch=2, 
        verbose=1,
        validation_split=0.2, # validation_split vs validation_data
        shuffle=True, 
        callbacks=[model_checkpoint])

    print('predict test data')
    imgs_mask_test = model.predict(imgs_test, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
    print(imgs_mask_test.shape())
    print(imgs_mask_test)
    np.save("./results/imgs_mask_test.npy", imgs_mask_test)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It is not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Fix indentation first - we can't ignore indentation errors as they might be the cause